# How to display Vertical line in android

Tags: android, line

how to display Vertical line in android with specific height.I know how to display Horizontal line but iam unable to find solution to the way to display Vertical line.

Comment: if some answer helped you, then please accept that answer so it can help others too.

Answer (score 13):

Using a view  we can do

Try below :

```
  <View
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000"
    />
```

Comment: any idea why this won't be visible while contained in a linear/relative layout?

Answer (score 2):

It could be also `1x1 nine-patch png` stretched to 1xn.